# Is Prolog really based on the closed-world assumption?

Tags: prolog, logic

Under the [closed-world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption),

> what is not currently known to be true, is false

Prolog's semantics is often said to follow the closed-world assumption, for example, [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/12532):

> Prolog is based on closed world assumption (CWA) -- that is, if a proposition is not in the fact database and not derivable from the fact database, then it is not true.

However, it doesn't quite behave this way. Under CWA, I'd expect

```
?- a.
false.
```

But instead, in SWI-Prolog, I get:

```
?- a.
ERROR: Undefined procedure: a/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Why is that? Is it wrong to say that Prolog is based on CWA?

Comment: What can be said is that the `\+` operator is based on a computable approximation of the Closed World Assumption. I am currently trying to write a little guide on this, [see here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/other_notes/about_negation). (All errors are mine etc. and I haven't even read Clarke's original paper in detail yet; time flies.).

Comment: In fact, what you are getting here is a specific exception. If you classify the atomic ground goals for which Prolog throws "undefined procedure exception" into the set of atomic ground goals that are mapped to FALSE, you are back to a super-extended CWA ... the Closed Multiverse Assumption?

Comment: Also not that all this talk about CWA only applies to the part of Prolog that has a logical interpretation in first-order (classical? more like intuitionistic positive!) logic and doesn't use `\+` itself. (I'm not even sure how to think about proofs which involve N>1 `\+` on any path through the proof tree.)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer : That was a wonderful write up on `double negation`. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When talking about Closed-World Assumption (CWA) in the context of Prolog, a distinction must be made between *unknown* predicates versus predicates *known* to the (runtime) system. In both cases, predicates with or without clauses.

Calling an *unknown* predicate will, by default, raise a predicate existence error. There's a standard flag, `unknown` (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:unknown), whose default value is `error`, that can be set to `fail` (or `warning`). That will give you the behavior that you're apparently looking for. Still, I strongly advise you to keep the flag set to its default value of `error`, as it allows easier detection of programming mistakes (e.g. typos in predicate names or arity).

What makes a predicate *known* to the runtime? Predicate directives or predicate clauses. The most familiar example is the `dynamic/1` directive. If your code consists solely of the following text:

```
:- dynamic(foo/1).
```

Then, after compiling and loading, you can expect:

```
?- foo(_).
no.
```

But other directives have the same effect (e.g. `multifile/1` and `discontiguous/1`, assuming that is a standard conforming Prolog implementation!).

Thus, for *known* predicates, the interpretation of CWA in Prolog is simple: what we cannot prove to be true, is false. I.e. *negation by failure*, which is **not** the same as *logical negation*. The name Prolog comes from *programming in logic* but Prolog also aims to be a pragmatic and practical programming language.

What's lacking in Prolog (and is provided by e.g. [Logtalk](https://logtalk.org/rationale.html#declaring-a-predicate-vs-defining-a-predicate)) is being able to *declare* a predicate **without** being forced to declare it as dynamic, or multifile, or ... or requiring providing clauses for it (see e.g. this [example](https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/closed_world_assumption)). This provides simpler and clearer CWA semantics: calling a declared predicate with no clauses fails (without the need of messing with the problematic `unknown` flag); calling a non-declared predicate raises a predicate existence error.

Hope this helps. Searching for *negation as failure* should provide further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Your query must be in the language itself, for `a` to be a proposition `a/0` must be in the language, i.e., defined as a predicate. All nullary predicates in the language are propositions. You cannot query a new term as predicate without first adding it to the language.

For `a/1` when you define it just as `a(b).` it is in the language,  then the query `a(X), dif(X,b)` will fail since the prolog system does not know any other terms that satisfy it and assuming close world there are no other.