# Why does the negation as a failure work with \+ is_list but not with \+ is_flat?

Tags: prolog

```
flattenList(L,FL) :-
   must_be(list,L),       % if L is unbound, the predicate does not terminate; make sure it's a list
   flattenList(L,[],FL).

% ===
% flattenList(+In, +Suffix, +Flattened)
%
% "'Flattened' is the flattened 'In' (which is [In] if 'In' is not a list),
% with the list 'Suffix' suffixed.
% ===

flattenList([],Suf,Suf).

flattenList([H|T],Suf,Flat):- 
   flattenList(T,Suf,LargerSuf),
   flattenList(H,LargerSuf,Flat).

flattenList(H,Suf,[H|Suf]):- \+ is_list(H).  % use NAF
```

This version works correctly, but I am wondering why if I use the negation on a different predicate name like

```
flattenList(H,Suf,[H|Suf]):- \+ is_flat_list(H).
```

It will not work. Any info on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Prolog really based on the closed-world assumption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014705/is-prolog-really-based-on-the-closed-world-assumption)

Comment: yes it does help clarify a bit ,b ut I am still a bit fuzzy as to why is_list works and is_flat_list does not work since they are both predicates not predefined. is is_list special in some way?

Comment: I had to reflect a bit on the code of flattenList/2 (although it _is_ the `flatten/2` which appears in O'Keefe's "The Craft of Prolog on p. 97). I have allowed myself to replace it with a commented version. Feel free to roll back.

Comment: Well, `is_list/1` is predefined, but `is_flat_list/1` is not. So `\+ is_flat_list(H)` should actually throw an error. And if defined, `is_list/1` and `is_flat_list/1` are not equivalent at all: `is_list([[a]])` succeeds but `is_flat_list([[a]])` fails.